# Is there a way to catch an WillRotateToInterfaceOrientation event from an UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

every UIViewController has a method called willRotateToInterface.

Is it possible to do this within a UIView too?

Does this match the idea of model view controller ?

The only way I can think of is to send the event from the UIViewController to the UIView.

Is there a global variable for the current orientation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Observe `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationDidChange:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

...

- (void)orientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSLog(@"new orientation = %d", [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]);
}
```

[UIDevice Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html)

I should note that yo uneed to add `-beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` when you want these notifications to be sent, and call `-endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` when you want them to stop. There is a battery impact of generating these, so you should only do so when your view is on screen. `UIViewController` does all this for you, so if you have a view controller, it is worth letting it do the work.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to adjust view to new size/layout when orientation changes, you should just override its `layoutSubviews` method.

It will be called whenever size of the view changes, which usually happens when view is rotated.

Comment: This would be a perfect solution if the changes made in a layoutSubviews call were animatable.

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to a global notification and get a call when the device is rotated, it wont do anything for you though..

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(didRotate:)
name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```